# Auto-drafts Feature using MVC 5

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, autosave

I am trying to implement the auto draft save feature like Gmail in a MVC5 application. However, the draft data that I want to save covers an entire page in my application.

The page uses twitter Bootstrap, and includes a number of modal pop-ups, supports jQuery draggables and droppables and charts. The pop-ups include DateRangePicker and few more input fields as well.

**My idea is to use an ajax post, continuous on an interval, that stores the entire HTML of that page into the database along with timestamps and other required data.**

My **doubts** are :

1) Is it advisable to take up the above approach to achieve it? or can we do this in a better way?

2) The **page uses html helpers along with model specification and C# razors**, so how to store these definitions in the database and retrieve them back without tampering their functionality?

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

**P.S. I am using MS-SQL 2008 server with Entity framework.**